How do I create a function that deletes a row when checkbox is true
Basically I have a spreadsheet where I need a code that deletes the row that I check the checkbox in. Now I have code that is doing this, but the code runs across the whole spreadsheet not just the 2 specific sheets. Therefore, when something on another sheet is marked true or 1 in the area that is checked the code activates and causes issues. This code runs on an on edit trigger as well.
I have tried this block of code which does delete the row as I mentioned but runs no matter the sheet im on. Now I tried to add a checkSheet function as you can see but did not work (may of done it wrong).
function deleteCheckedBoxes() {

checkSheet();

const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

const activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
const activeRow = activeRange.getRow();
const activeColumn = activeRange.getColumn();

let rangeUpdatedValue =  activeRange.getValue();

if(activeColumn == 5 && rangeUpdatedValue == true){

  sheet.deleteRow(activeRow);

}


I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to delete the row when the function deleteCheckedBoxes is run.
You want to run the script to the specific sheets.
From your showing script, I guessed that you wanted to directly run the function deleteCheckedBoxes although you have already installed the function as the OnEdit trigger.

In this case, how about the following modification?
Modified script:
Please set the sheet names to sheetNames of the sheets you want to run the script.
function deleteCheckedBoxes() {
  const sheetNames = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2",,,]; // Please set your sheet names you want to use this script.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheetNames.includes(sheet.getSheetName())) {
    const activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
    const activeRow = activeRange.getRow();
    const activeColumn = activeRange.getColumn();
    if (activeColumn == 5 && activeRange.isChecked()) {
      sheet.deleteRow(activeRow);
    }
  }
}


When this script is run, the script is run to the sheet names of sheetNames.
In order to confirm the checkbox, isChecked() can also be used.

References:

includes()
isChecked()

